# Example of set with a special property

Tags: real-analysis

Is it possible to give an example of countable set, with uncountable derived set, such that intersection with this set and its derived set is empty?

I know that if given set is uncountable, then it is impossible. But what if set is countable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider taking middle points of middle thirds from Cantor's set. Every point of that set is isolated, hence the set is countable. Derived set is Cantor set itself, and all points are not in Cantor's set by definition. Hence, this set is needed example.